# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing a custom database connection DLL

Tags: asp.net, debugging, .net-3.5, iis-7, windows-7

I'm having issues with vs2010 debugger. I have an application that uses a forms log-in then uses a custom connection .dll to connect to the database. The web application seems to run as expected when accessing it straight through IE, but when I use the debugger it throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException trying to access the connection DLL located in the GAC. It seems to be a permissions problem for the user that the debugger uses. This is a little outside of my scope of knowledge.

Here is my iis7 settings

```
<applicationPools>
  <add name="DefaultAppPool" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Classic" startMode="OnDemand">
    <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" pingResponseTime="00:05:00" />
  </add>
```

Application Set up on server

```
<application path="##AppName##" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="##APP Path##" />
</application>
```